# Inserting unique items into a Meteor collection from an asynchronous callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have defined a callback function with the Meteor.bindEnvironment wrapper as described in the
[Meteor Async Guide](http://gist.io/3443021). I used the wrapper so that a Meteor collection would be available to this asynchronous callback. Within the callback I am trying to insert only documents with a unique values for an attribute called 'title'. I have found several resources demonstrating the Mongo way of handling this, but the required functions (e.g. findAndModify or upsert option for find) are not yet implemented by Meteor.

I have resorted to performing a query for incoming title's value and inserting a new document if the query returns no matching documents. However, this fails due to the asynchronous nature of the callback and duplicates end up being inserted into the collection.

Is there a Meteor or Node.js pattern for wrapping a critical section like this with a lock?

Thanks!

Comment: The most simple way is send data to server and make synchronous operations at the server.

Comment: Make `title` unique in mongo? Any duplicate inserts should fail then

Comment: @Denis The code is already running server side. The callback is triggered by a rabbitMQ message passing queue that also runs on the server.

Comment: @Xyand My DB experience is in SQL and enforcing a unique constraint on the 'title' attribute is something that I looked into. It appears that the method of doing so in Mongo is not currently implemented in Meteor

Comment: I use Fibers and recive messages through RabbitMQ too. See how to use fibers and rabbit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508769/how-to-execute-a-python-script-from-server-side-javascript/18510963#18510963

Comment: It has nothing to do with Meteor. Simply connect to your Mongo instance and run `db.collection.ensureIndex`. From this moment and on duplicate inserts should fail.

Answer (score 0):

If only one actor (client or server) is doing the polling, I don't see how you would get an async bypass of your 'already received' block list unless your update call was going off too often.  Is there nothing in the api to only return msgs after a timestamp, or to subscribe only to changes?

If you have multiple clients each polling a common outside source for updates, then trying to sync to a merged common collection, (which you don't say, but would have the problem you describe),

Make each stream unique by title + userid.

You also may want just local collections on the client to track what the client has seen, and a separate one on the server if you are trying for an audit trail.

Comment: There is no polling involved. The callback is completely asynchronous so that it is called whenever a message is added to the queue on the server side.

Comment: "However, this fails due to the asynchronous nature of the callback and duplicates end up being inserted into the collection"

Sound like you need a 'debounce' where you block getting the subsequent new messages until the previous callback has completed.